# PyTorch: inconsistent pretrained VGG output

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, torchvision

When loading a pretrained VGG network with the `torchvision.models` module and using it to classify an arbitrary RGB image, the network's output differs noticeably from invocation to invocation. Why does this happen? From my understanding no part of the VGG forward pass should be non-deterministic.

Here's an MCVE:

```
import torch
from torchvision.models import vgg16

vgg = vgg16(pretrained=True)

img = torch.randn(1, 3, 256, 256)

torch.all(torch.eq(vgg(img), vgg(img))) # result is 0, but why?
```

Comment: (1) try in `eval` mode: `vgg.eval()`.  (2) try comparing using [`torch.allclose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.allclose) - due to floating point issues the outputs may not be identical but are very close to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vgg16` has a [`nn.Dropout`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#dropout2d) layer that, during training, *randomly* drops 50% of its inputs. During test time you should "switch off" this behavior by setting the mode of the net to "eval" mode:

```
vgg.eval()
torch.all(torch.eq(vgg(img), vgg(img)))
```

> ```
> Out[73]: tensor(1, dtype=torch.uint8)
> ```

Note that there are other layers with random behavior and different behavior for training and evaluation (e.g., [BatchNorm](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#batchnorm2d)). Therefore, it is important to switch to [`eval()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.eval) mode before evaluating a trained model.